# Doubt on a vector calculus identity $\nabla\times(f\nabla g)$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

Let $f$ and $g$ be two scalar function of several real variables

$$
f,g:X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$
$$
f,g\in C^2({\mathbb{R}^3})
$$
Calculate
$$
\nabla\times(f\cdot\nabla{g})
$$
where $\nabla\times$ is the *curl* vector operator.

I've found the identity 
$$
\nabla\times(f\cdot\nabla{g}) = \nabla{f}\times\nabla{g}
$$
where $\nabla{f}\times\nabla{g}$ is the vectorial product between the gradient respectively of function $f$ and $g$. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  Explicitly, both sides are

$$ (f_{{y}}g_{{z}}-f_{{z}}g_{{y}})\, \mathbf{i}+(-f_{{x}}g_{{z
}}+f_{{z}}g_{{x}})\, \mathbf{j}+(f_{{x}}g_{{y}}-f_{{y}}g_{{
x}})\, \mathbf{k}$$

where subscripts denote partial derivatives.